# How long would it take for a container in vacuum to leak half of its air?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, air, statistics

Let's say I know the size of the container, size of the hole the air leaks through, pressure the air is under and temperature of the air if that helps anything. Is it possible to calculate this only from these variables? What is the formula for how fast air leaks out of a hole?

Comment: http://www.geoffreylandis.com/higgins.html

Comment: *"Is it possible to calculate..."* Of course, it's possible. But, I don't think we appreciate formula suggestion questions..!

Comment: The general problem is very difficult as it depends on many things: the volume, pressure and viscosity of the gas, the size of the hole, the thickness of the walls and so on.